# Sparse matrix addition condition

Tags: c++, c, sparse-matrix

I was reading code for addition of sparse matrix and came across this condition

```
if( sp1[0][0] != sp2[0][0] || sp1[0][1] != sp2[0][1] )
{
    printf("Invalid matrix size ");
    exit(0);
}
```

Couldn't understand why the number of non-zero rows and columns should be same ?
Sorry I am a newbie.

The whole code is [here](http://www.cprograms.in/Array/sparse-matrix-addition.html)

Comment: From the explanation in your link the number of rows and columns should be identical to perform an addition.

Comment: Why should it be same, we can add even if it wasn't.

Comment: Ask the author of that code. I'm not sure about _"we can add even if it wasn't"_.

Comment: Even on this site it is given it should be same [here](http://www.thecrazyprogrammer.com/2014/03/c-program-for-addition-of-two-sparse-matrices.html)

Comment: That blog entry contains a bunch of horribly unreadable code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In matrix addition the number rows in the first matrix need to equal the number of rows in the second matrix.

The same is true about the columns.

The number of columns of the first matrix has to equal the number of columns of the second.

That is what that code you posted shows.
Here is a quote from the linked code:

> In this matrix sparse matrix is stored as follows
>
> s[0][0]=Total rows in sparse matrix
>
> s[0][1]=Total columns in sparse matrix
>
> s[0][2]=Total number of non-zero values

Comment: Its not matrix addition, its sparse matrix addition. The number of rows denote number of nonzero rows and same for column

Comment: I'm pretty sure that in the linked code, `sp[0][0]` and `sp[0][1]` hold the dimensions of the actual matrix.

Comment: It may be sparse, but you still can't add matrices of differing dimensions. I agree that only knowing the number of non-zero rows is not helpful because you do not know how many more rows with value zero there are. In order to tell if the matrices can be added you need the exact dimensions. Only having the "non-zero" dimensions is useless.

Comment: Yes @Ian Abbott you are correct. I will edit my answer to elaborate.

Comment: My bad. I thougth 's[0][0]' = number of rows that contain non zero elements.Thanks for clearification.

Comment: I suppose you could define a non-standard form of matrix addition where the resulting matrix has its number of rows set to the maximum number of rows of its operands, and similarly for columns, with all new matrix elements taking the value 0. You could omit the dimensions check for that form of addition.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you could. Who is to say which positions are common to both though? Is the result a composite of both matrices with one pasted below or to the right of the other? Do we take the top left corner of both to be the same relative position?